# How create a form in runtime in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

My application has 2 parts:
1- server in java language
2- client in Angular 4.
 In client I call a service that returns a string value like that: `"text,button,textarea"` that indicates the elements of a form. Then in client I should, base on this return value, create an appropriate form. My problem is that all of them must happen on `runtime` and I do not know how I can create this kind of form? I search on the Internet with this title **How create dynamic forms in Angular 4?** but the results were unrelated to my problem

Comment: I assume you already looked at this: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: @ChauTran Thank you so much!! it was exactly what I need. In my project, now I am able to add elements on the fly and in runtime.